# Calculating exponential moving averages

Tags: javascript, mathematics

I'm wanting to calculate exponential moving averages of a variable, `distance`. Is the logic (and math) correct in the below code?

`time` and `lastTime` are millisecond-precise timestamps in seconds – the former is the current time, the latter is the time of the last calculations.

`lastA` etc are the exponential moving averages from the last calculations.

`a` etc will be left with the calculated exponential moving averages.

```
var distance = ...;
var a = Math.pow(1.16, -(time-lastTime)),
    b = Math.pow(1.19, -(time-lastTime)),
    c = Math.pow(1.22, -(time-lastTime)),
    d = Math.pow(1.26, -(time-lastTime)),
    e = Math.pow(1.30, -(time-lastTime)),
    f = Math.pow(1.35, -(time-lastTime)),
    g = Math.pow(1.40, -(time-lastTime));
a = a*lastA + (1-a)*distance;
b = b*lastB + (1-b)*distance;
c = c*lastC + (1-c)*distance;
d = d*lastD + (1-d)*distance;
e = e*lastE + (1-e)*distance;
f = f*lastF + (1-f)*distance;
g = g*lastG + (1-g)*distance;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is border line a bad question, as not enough code is given to properly review it.

The variables a -> g look terrible, I would create an array with the numbers you need:

```
var dataPoints = [1.16,1.19,1.22,1.26,1.30,1.35,1.40];
```

Then I would would loop over those points and create an averages object

```
var averages = {},
    value, x;
for(var i = 0, length = dataPoints.length ; i < length ; i++ ){
  value = dataPoints[i];
  x = Math.pow(value, -(time-lastTime));
  averages[value] = x * lastAverages[value] + (1-x) * distance;
}
```

I cannot tell whether the math is correct, if it is not correct, then this question does not belong here :)

Comment: Why use objects for storage, though? Just use plain arrays for `averages` and `lastAverages`. Indices will match the `dataPoints` array. Using numbers as property names is iffy, as they'll get treated as strings and whatnot.

Comment: @200_success I think the code conveys my point. The original code cannot run, so I cannot test and fix mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Either I'm confused by your notation, or you may have implemented something completely different from an [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average), which is traditionally defined as

> \$S_{t} = \alpha Y_{t-1} + (1-\alpha) S_{t-1}\$
>
> where
>
> - \$\alpha\$ is the decay rate
> - \$Y_{t}\$ is the value at time \$t\$
> - \$S_{t}\$ is the exponential moving average at time \$t\$.

How do your variables correspond to those in the definition?  Let's just consider one of your letters instead of all seven:

> ```
> var distance = ...;
> var a = Math.pow(1.16, -(time-lastTime));
> a = a*lastA + (1-a)*distance;
> ```

I'm guessing

- `a` corresponds to \$\alpha\$, and you adjust the decay per timeslice based on the duration of the timeslice
- `lastA` corresponds to \$Y_{t-1}\$
- `distance` corresponds to \$S_{t-1}\$

But then, I'm confused:

1. What's the purpose of the seven letters `a` … `g`?  To track the results using multiple decay rates?  If so, wouldn't the different decay rates result in a different series *S<sub>t</sub>* for each decay rate?
2. Why do all seven cases all share the same `distance` — isn't it the point to have a different `distance` series for each case?
3. Why do you assign the final result to `a` (= the decay rate) rather than to `distance` or something?